# git: forget to save local changes but reset to past commit

Tags: git

I made some changes in my local working directory, I forget to save/commit them, but I command `git reset HEAD~1` to go back to my previous commit. How do I recover my local work?

Comment: Short answer: you don't. At least not with git. You will have to use another tool, such as your editor (if it saves history) or the operating system.

Comment: @TonyNguyen : did you run `git reset HEAD~1` ? or `git reset --hard HEAD~1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only ran `git reset HEAD~1` (without using `--hard`), `git` hasn't changed to content of your files on disk. You can check that, in your IDE, your files still contain the modifications you had before your `reset` command.

The only things that changed are :

- the active commit : you can come back to your previous state by inspecting `git reflog` to see what was the `<sha>` of the commit before your `git reset HEAD~1` action, and run `git reset <sha>`
- your staged files : `git reset` has unstaged your staged files if you had any, and there is no easy way to get back their state.

---

If you rang `git reset --hard`, then unfortunately @Code-Apprentice's comment applies : git has reverted the content on disk without saving it first. Check if you have a history of your files in your IDE, or use a file restoration tool for your OS.

Comment: I ran `git reset HEAD~1`. Yes, you're right. all my current contents were there. I was in a different branch so I could not see all my `master` contents.